# how to create multiple worksheets in a loop and add corresponding result set to the sheets in excel using java and poi

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-poi

i have a table in ms sql server having data like:

col1   col2

123    dsk

456    dsk

789    mrk

450    dsk

i have to  write the resultset to ms excel using java and poi. i have to create sheets by name dsk and mrk and add the respective resultset to respective sheets. i am able to write the resultset successfully, but all the data come under only one sheet. how to do this? (may be using for or while or.. loops)

Comment: sheet dsk should contain (col1,col2),(123,dsk),(456,dsk),(450,dsk) and sheet mrk should contain (col1,col2),(789,mrk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Iterate through your initial sheet col2 values
- For every col2 value call WorkBook `createSheet(col2_value)`

Comment: thanks for your inputs. i am able to create the sheets using while loop but i am not able to write the respective data to respective sheets. all the data are written to only one sheet.

Comment: you mean to the WorkBook ??

Comment: no no worksheet. i am able to create the sheets in while loop using while(rs.next())  HSSFSheet ws  = workbook.createSheet(name);

Comment: but all the data comes into only one sheet and does not appear sheet wise. sheet "dsk" should contain (col1,col2),(123,dsk),(456,dsk),(450,dsk) and sheet "mrk" should contain (col1,col2),(789,mrk)

Comment: solved!! just a matter of 1 line to be added. thanks